# Using global variables in Python

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter, python-2.7

I am using Tkinter to help me build a FTP client, in this client I am trying to get the selected  information from a tk listbox. So I have a button that starts the download but what ever the reason is it pops up with the error "

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Volumes/LEGO FLASH/ftp.py", line 23, in Download
    filename = stuff
NameError: global name 'stuff' is not defined"
```

Below I have the code for you to look at:

```
# Import the FTP object from ftplib
from ftplib import FTP
from Tkinter import *
import os

app = Tk()
app.title("FTP")
app.geometry("300x300")

lines = []
#[lines.replace(",", "\n")for lines in lines]
#lines = lines.replace(',','\n')

def handleDownload(block):
    file.write(block)
    print ".",

def append_line(line):
    lines.append(line)

#This is where I am caught-------> 
def Download():

    filename = stuff

    file = open(filename, 'wb')

    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, handleDownload)


    ftp.close()

def login():
    try:
        ftp.login(username.get(),password.get())
    except:
        error = Label(app, text = "Invalid USERNAME OR PASSWORD")


    label2 = Label(app, text = "Welcome to Steam Engine").pack()
    username.forget()
    password.forget()
    button.forget()

    app.geometry("800x500")

    download = Button(app, text = "Download!!!!!", command = Download)
    download.pack(side = "left", pady = "5")

    scrollBar.pack(fill = Y, side = "right", padx = "2")

    #ftp.cwd('The_Store')

    stuff = Listbox(app, height = "700", width = "500")
    ftp.retrlines('NLST', append_line)
    for i in lines:
        stuff.insert(END, i)
    stuff.pack(padx = "10", pady = "10")

    stuff.config(yscrollcommand = scrollBar.set)
    scrollBar.config(command = stuff.yview)



ftp = FTP('sciphigames.com')
label = Label(app, text = "Login").pack(pady = "10")

scrollBar = Scrollbar(app)

username = StringVar(None)
username = Entry(app, text = "Username: ")
username.pack(pady = "2")

password = StringVar(None)
password = Entry(app, text = "Password: ")
password.pack(pady = "2")

button = Button(app, text = "Login!", command = login)
button.pack(pady = "10")

app.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a full stack trace plase?

Comment: you should avoid using this kind of global variable. And even if you do, don't call it `stuff`. Seriously, don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what the purpose is with your `stuff` variable, but the problems you are experiencing probably stem from the way you are using it.

First, you are using it as argument to `login` (which, by the way should take no arguments). You assign to this variable from the `login` function, and refer to another variable with the same name in your `Download` function.

Again, not being sure what I understand what you want to do with the `stuff` variable, I would try something like

```
.....

app.geometry("300x300")

stuff = None # <<<<----

lines = []

.....

#This is where I am caught-------> 
def Download():
    global stuff # <<<<----

    filename = stuff

    ......

    ftp.close()

def login():
    global stuff # <<<<----

    ......

    stuff = Listbox(app, height = "700", width = "500")
    ftp.retrlines('NLST', append_line)
    for i in lines:
        stuff.insert(END, i)
    stuff.pack(padx = "10", pady = "10")

    stuff.config(yscrollcommand = scrollBar.set)
    scrollBar.config(command = stuff.yview)


......
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#This is where I am caught-------> 
def Download():

    filename = stuff
```

what is stuff here ?? it is not a global variable, it seems to be a parameter of `login`, but not of `Download` method.

If you want to do `stuff` a global variable (probably not the better choice), use the [global statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#global).

```
# Import the FTP object from ftplib
from ftplib import FTP
from Tkinter import *
import os

# define the global stuff
global stuff

...
def Download():

    global stuff

    filename = stuff

...
```

A better way to handle this would be to create an object around all of this ::

```
class NetworkApp(object):
   def login(self):
      # here put all the previous code of login

      # here we change the callback to self.Download
      download = Button(app, text = "Download!!!!!", command = self.Download)

      # here we're creating a stuff member
      self.stuff = Listbox(app, height = "700", width = "500")


    def Download(self):
        filename = self.stuff  # here we use the stuff member
        file = open(filename, 'wb')
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, handleDownload)
        ftp.close()
#...
net_app = NetworkApp()
button = Button(app, text = "Login!", command = net_app.login)
```

Comment: Stuff is the variable I used for the listbox

Comment: And I don't know how to make a global variable I am sort of new to this type of Python Programming

Comment: @user1114215 : yes, but when `Download` is called, it can't know what is `stuff`.

Comment: Like I said I am kind of new to this whole thing with global variable I understand the basics of it but I don't know how to make a variable into a global one.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is put "global" in front of the variable

```
global var1
```